# Can AZ ML workbench reference multiple data sources from Data Prep Transform Dataflow expression

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Using AZ ML workbench for a class project (required tool) I coded the desired logic below in an exploration notebook but cannot find a way to include this into a Data-prep Transform Data flow.

`all_columns = df.columns
sum_columns = [col_name for col_name in all_columns if col_name not in ['NPI', 'Gender', 'State', 'Credentials', 'Specialty']]
sum_op_columns = list(set(sum_columns) & set(df_op['Drug Name'].values))`

The logic is using the column names from one data source df_op (opioid drugs) to choose which subset of columns to include from another data source df (all drugs). When adding a py script/expression Transform Data Flow I'm only seeing the ability to reference the single df. Alternatives?

Answer (score -1):

I may have a way for you to access both data frames.

In Workbench, once you have the data sources that you need loaded, right click on one and select "Generate Data Access Code File".

[image: Data sources]

Once there you're automatically given code to access that specific file. However, you can use the same code to access the other files.

In the screenshot above, I have two data sources. I can use the below code to access them both as a `pandas` data frame and manipulate them as I need.

```
df_salary = datasource.load_datasource('SalaryData.dsource')
df_startup = datasource.load_datasource('50-Startups.dsource')
```

I believe from there you can save your updated data frame to a CSV and then use that in the `train` script.

Hope that helps or at least points you to another solution.